# Highcharts bubble graph, custom marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts, bubble-chart

I have a bubble series that I want to use one point in one series as a custom marker.  The marker could be a star rendered based on the SVG implementation of HighCharts (5 point-star), or a URL image.

https://assets.mypatentideas.com/images/fiddle/star.png

```
 series: [{
            //  color: 'red',

         data: [                    
                { x: -0.95, y: 0.54, z: 0.93},
                { x: -0.15, y: 0.14, z: 1,   marker: {
                symbol: 'star'
            }}   

            ]
        },
        {
            //  color: 'red',
            data: [
                { x: 0.95, y: -0.54, z: 0.93},
                { x: 0.15, y: -0.14, z: 1,   marker: {
                symbol: 'starimage'
            } },


            ]
        }]
```

The idea is introduced here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mshaffer/kx62dztf/

For the image, resize so the w and h is equal to the radius if it were a true bubble.  For the SVG star, render so the radius of the star (center to any point) is this same bubble-radius.

Maybe the star needs to be its own series, which is fine.

Few relevant references:
https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3913511-allow-for-custom-symbols-when-using-bubble-chart
which points to http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/un9faeed/ and http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/renderer/ from http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer

Comment: So, the one thing I am not seeing in this post is an actual question. You have listed some of the references I might have posted in response, so we need to know what you have worked out based on those references, and what - specifically - you are looking for help with.

Comment: "I have a bubble series that I want to use one point in one series as a custom marker. The marker could be a star rendered based on the SVG implementation of HighCharts (5 point-star), or a URL image."   HOW TO MAKE A CUSTOM MARKER FOR HIGH CHARTS BUBBLE EITHER AS AN IMAGE OR A SVG?

Comment: This has a homework smell about it. Looks like the OP text is verbatim from some assignment. You can check the API docs on `marker` that should get you going.

Comment: I would guess that you're better off using a scatter series. Look for the multitude of examples of making a custom marker in general, and provide the radius for each marker in the point objects in your data.

Comment: @wergeld, homework really, you still in grade school

Answer (score 1):

The code from the uservoice (allowing different symbols for bubbles) can be combined with the code from [the demo with custom markers](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/). You need to define you own shape and then you can use it as a marker symbol.

```
  Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.star = function(x, y, w, h) {
return [
  'M', x, y + 0.4 * h,
  'L', x + 0.35 * w, y + 0.35 * h,
  'L', x + 0.5 * w, y,
  'L', x + 0.65 * w, y + 0.35 * h,
  'L', x + w, y + 0.4 * h,
  'L', x + 0.75 * w, y + 0.65 * h,
  'L', x + 0.85 * w, y + h,
  'L', x + 0.5 * w, y + 0.8 * h,
  'L', x + w * 0.15, y + h,
  'L', x + 0.25 * w, y + 0.65 * h,
  'Z'
];
};

if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.star = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.star;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/un9faeed/3/

example: https://jsfiddle.net/kx62dztf/2/

Comment: Nice example.  What about a URL symbol; e.g., a PNG?

Comment: here is some code to generate any regular polygon in replace of a circle ... sides > 3, radius is the same as a circle would have:

Comment: $points = array();
   for($a = 0;$a <= 360; $a += 360/$sides)
    {
    $points[] = $x + $radius * cos(deg2rad($a));
    $points[] = $y + $radius * sin(deg2rad($a));
    }

Comment: https://wizard.mypatentideas.com/r/online.nnp/d40b32871ec7a4755e912f781222b190/2e153dc325e98060fb2456068859267ca77d727c825bb9f3401f6d25414691ee26a5294e9c19/ae9f5ea6b1e30759575a0afd5045d0fca934557d380f78c60aa4f4c1984b6f45a4ae0fa34502d9a8015b/

Comment: my link above, the legend doesn't seem to behave as expected.  Any thoughts?